# F# Exception handling: how to parse number in ReadLine()?

Tags: f#

I'm trying to get the input number from the command line input:

```
let mutable guess = Console.ReadLine() |> System.Int32.Parse
```

This works fine as long as the input is a number; except when the input is an alphabetical string, say, `kdf`, the program will exit with a `System.TypeInitilizationException`.

How to handle strings in console input?

**Update**

I'm trying to write the *guessing game* in F#. Here is the whole program:

```
open System

printfn "Guess the number"

let secretNum = System.Random().Next(1,101)

let mutable continueLooping = true 

while continueLooping do

    printfn "Please input your guess."

    let mutable input = Console.ReadLine() 

    let result =
        match Int32.TryParse input with
        | (true, result) -> Some(result) 
        | (false, _) -> printfn "Please input a number!"; None

    let guess = Option.get result

    printfn "You guessed: %A" guess

    if guess < secretNum then printfn "Too small!"
    else if guess > secretNum then printfn "Too big!"
    else do 
        printfn "You win!" 
        continueLooping <- false



[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

This program does the right work except it couldn't deal with the invalid input problem. I'm new to programming, maybe this is a quite obvious question to .NET programmer. I'm afraid beginners often have dumb question.

Comment: What do you want to do if the input is not a number? You could handle the exception (good option if invalid data is truly exceptional) or use [`Int32.TryParse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) functions and deal with non-parse in the pipeline (remember the `bool` return and out param in the docs becomes `bool * int` tuple with the F# compiler).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I usually do

```
match System.Int32.TryParse input with
| (true, number) -> ...
| (false, _)     -> ....
```

works like a charm for all the `TryXY` patterns in .net too ;)

### example

```
F# Interactive for F# 3.1 (Open Source Edition)
Freely distributed under the Apache 2.0 Open Source License

For help type #help;;

> let tryInt input = match System.Int32.TryParse input with | (true, number) -> Some number | _ -> None;;

val tryInt : input:string -> int option

> tryInt "55";;
val it : int option = Some 55
> tryInt "no";;
val it : int option = None
>
```

### remarks

My guess is that you want to query your user till he enters a valid integer. So you can use the function I just gave you to do this with a single recursive *loop-like* function:

```
let rec queryAnInt () =
    printf "please input an integer " 
    let input = System.Console.ReadLine()
    match System.Int32.TryParse input with
    | (true, number) -> number
    | _              -> printfn "sorry - you did not enter an integer"
                        queryAnInt ()
```

Now `queryAnInt ()` will ask the user for an integer till he gave one and return just it (without the `Option` you seem to have a problem with)

### your program

Here are a few things I see in your program:

- First the obvious things: **you coded everything right into the module**, when you really want to have it in the `main` method and in functions - that will get you into problems quickly
- you match the guess into `result` as an `Option` only to throw all you gained away in the very next line `Option.get result` which will throw an error when the `result` was `None` (when the user did not enter a number) - this **is your real problem**
- you use a global mutable variable and an imperative loop - both are *functional code smells*

A simple rewrite (without the ugly mutable) could look like this:

```
open System

let rec queryGuess () =
    printf "please input your guess " 
    let input = Console.ReadLine()
    match System.Int32.TryParse input with
    | (true, number) when number >= 1 && number <= 100
                     -> number
    | _              -> printfn "sorry - please enter a number between 1 and 100"
                        queryGuess ()

let rec guess secret nrTriesLeft =
    if nrTriesLeft = 0 then printfn "Sorry you lost" else
    match queryGuess () with
    | g when g < secret ->
        printfn "Too small!"
        guess secret (nrTriesLeft - 1)
    | g when g > secret ->
        printfn "Too big!"
        guess secret (nrTriesLeft - 1)
    | g when g = secret ->
        printfn "You win!"
    | _ -> failwith "impossible case" 

let game () = 
    printfn "Guess my secret number - it's between 1 and 100"

    let secretNum = System.Random().Next(1,101)

    guess secretNum 7 // 7 tries should always be enough - bonus question: why?

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 
    game ()
    0
```

This way you can easily extent to let's say only certain number of retries too (just change the `guess` function a bit - you should **try it!**)

I hope this finally helps you deal with your syntax issues

Comment: I tried this: `let mutable input = Console.ReadLine() 
    
    let result =
        match Int32.TryParse input with
        | (true, result) -> Some(result) 
        | (false, _) -> printfn "Please input a number!"; None
            
    let guess = Option.get result ` But still get the `System.TypeInitializatinException`.

Comment: can you please add all of your code to your question so that we can try to compile it ourselves? Also I added a full session in F#-Interactive so you can see it in action

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay. I've put the whole program to the post. I've read your `example` and `remarks`. I tied to `let guess =
        let rec queryAnInt () =
            printf "please input an integer " 
            let input = System.Console.ReadLine()
            match System.Int32.TryParse input with
            | (true, number) -> number
            | _              -> printfn "sorry - you did not enter an integer"
                                queryAnInt ()` the compiler said to `let rec queryAnInt`: `The block following this let is unfinished. Expect an expression.`

Comment: well it works for me (obvious you copy&pasted it into your program and has an issue after the code) - but I'll test your complete program and update my answer

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code is really clear, easy to read and understand. I learnt a lot in your answer. I tried to add max number of tries, only found out that I lost control in the recursive `guess` function. Recursion is elegant, but hard for beginners. Can you give me any clue?

Comment: sure - you basically add another argument `nrTriesLeft` and the first thing you check is if those are 0 - if yes then you print some "I am sorry you lost" message and do nothing else (just as in the win case) in the else branch you just keep what is already there - see the answer - I will add it ;)

Comment: Ah, so elegant! *Add another argument* is the key! I tried to add another variable -- only lead to ugly mutable counter. For the bonus question: I guess the game taker could use `divide-and-conquer` method, 7 times would be enough to find a number from 0 to 2^7 = 128. Is this the same idea from finding a person's name from a telephone book?

Comment: yep - exactly ;) - of course you might want to reduce the number of tries to keep the game interesting ;)

Comment: by the way: maybe you'll want to rename some of the functions - I'm not too happy with `guess` for example - but I am to lazy to think of a better name right now - have fun

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at [Int32.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

```
let parsed, guess = Console.ReadLine() |> System.Int32.TryParse
if parsed then ... else ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of your example with the mutable variable and loop:

```
open System

printfn "Guess the number"
let secretNum = System.Random().Next(1,101)

let mutable continueLooping = true 

while continueLooping do

    printfn "Please input your guess."

    let mutable input = Console.ReadLine() 

    let result =
        match Int32.TryParse input with
        | (true, result) -> Some(result) 
        | (false, _) -> None

    match result with
        |Some guess -> printfn "You guessed: %A" guess
                       if guess < secretNum then printfn "Too small!"
                       else if guess > secretNum then printfn "Too big!"
                       else do 
                          printfn "You win!" 
                          continueLooping <- false
        |None -> printfn "Your guess is not a valid number!"

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    printfn "%A" argv
    0 // return an integer exit code
```